# FluentValidation centralize a regex validator in validator extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, fluentvalidation

I have a validation rule that is common for many properties that I'd like to centralize to DRY, but while `NotEmpty()` rules and the like work fine, `Matches(...)` and other string-only validator rules don't compile.

No problem:

```
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> MustNotContainHtml<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder)       
    {
        return ruleBuilder.NotEmpty().WithMessage("Some message.");
    }
```

Understandably won't compile because uses `Matches(...)` which is string-only:

```
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> MustNotContainHtml<T, TProperty>(this IRuleBuilderOptions<T, TProperty> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.Matches("<[a-z!/?]|&#").WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' contains special HTML characters which is not allowed.");
    }
```

What rule builder signature is there available for string-only options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to reuse the actual `RegularExpressionValidator`:

```
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> MustNotContainHtml<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.SetValidator(new RegularExpressionValidator("<[a-z!/?]|&#")).WithMessage("Some custom message.");
    }
```

Comment: You can accept your own answers as well, which helps us with identifying questions needing help :)

Comment: I know, but still need to wait until tomorrow before permitted to ;-)

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore, due to the new update in FluentValidation :(